# Dificuldade em montar query para Search em múltiplas colunas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho 2 tabelas

**tab_user**

```
user_id | nome_user | tel_user
1       jão         888 
2       mari        999
3       jão         777
4       mari        666
```

**tab_produto**

```
id_produto | user_id| carac_a | carac_b | carac_c | carac_d
1          1          aaa       bbb       ccc       eee
2          1          mmm       ggg       ccc       eee
3          1          aaa       bbb       ccc       hhh
4          1          aaa       rrr       fff       www
5          1          aaa       bbb       ccc       ddd
6          1          xxx       bbb       ccc       ddd
7          1          xxx       zzz       ccc       ddd
8          1          aaa       zzz       ccc       ddd
```

O objetivo é ver se uma `string` da `math` em alguma coluna, estou tentando assim:

```
<?php
$sql = 
"SELECT * FROM 
tab_produto LEFT JOIN
(tab_user) ON 
(tab_user.user_id = tab_produto .user_id) WHERE
(`carac_a ` LIKE '%".$value."%') OR 
(`carac_b ` LIKE '%".$value."%') OR 
(`carac_c ` LIKE '%".$value."%') OR 
(`carac_d ` LIKE '%".$value."%')";
?>
```

Está ocorrendo  o seguinte:

Se eu enviar o conteúdo de qualquer campo ele trás os resultados, porém se eu passar mais de 1 ele retorna 0, exemplo:

```
`aaa` ->  retorna todas as linhas com `aaa`
`eee` ->  retorna todas as linhas com `eee`
`aaaeee` -> retorna 0
```

Sou um usuário iniciante em `SQL`, não sei se é o caminho correto ou se há outro totalmente diferente.

O objetivo é não importando a variedade de como apareça na string(sendo `aaabbb`, `ccceee`, `mmmgggccceee`) ele traga  linha que contenha ao menos o respectivo pedaço.

Sei que tá meio confuso, estou pensando em uma forma de deixar o mais claro possível.

Comment: no caso, se o você passa `aaaeee` deve trazer o que tem "aaa" e o que tem "eee"?

Comment: Sim...Isso mesmo

Comment: Em geral sqls ficam complexos à toa quando o modelo é ruim , seu modelo não está normalizado , normalizando sua tabela seu sql seria trivial

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução poderia ser

criar uma view

```
create view v_produto as
select id_produto,user_id,carac_a carac from tab_produto
union all
select id_produto,user_id,carac_b carac from tab_produto
union all
select id_produto,user_id,carac_c carac from tab_produto
union all
select id_produto,user_id,carac_d carac from tab_produto
```

o sql fica trivial

```
select *
from   v_produto
where  carac in ('aaa','bbb')
```

mas sigo recomendando a [normalização](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados) do modelo

Answer (score 0):

Admitindo que suas colunas que armazenam a sequência de caracteres (`carac_a`, `carac_b`, etc) sempre receberão algum dos possíveis valores pesquisados (`aaa`, `bbb`, etc), você precisa consultar se alguma das colunas contém a *string* de busca, não o contrário:

```
<?php
$sql = 
"SELECT * FROM 
tab_produto LEFT JOIN
(tab_user) ON 
(tab_user.user_id = tab_produto .user_id) WHERE
('%".$value."%' LIKE `carac_a`) OR 
('%".$value."%' LIKE `carac_b`) OR 
('%".$value."%' LIKE `carac_c`) OR 
('%".$value."%' LIKE `carac_d`)";
?>
```

Do jeito que seu código está ele só retornará caso alguma das colunas contenha toda a sequência passada (tipo `aaabbb`).